# How to convert JavaScript to JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I convert this into JQuery?

```
function contantForm()
{
    let Username = document.getElementById("Username").value;  //create element Id called Username
    let Emailinput = document.getElementById("Email").value; //create element Id called Emailinput
    alert("Thank you " + Username) //alerts user with thier username after clicking submit
    document.getElementById("Username").value=""; //get username Id from index page
    document.getElementById("Email").value=""; //get email Id from index page
    document.getElementById("Phone").value=""; //get phone Id from index page
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: There is nothing you need to do. It already works.

Comment: Change ```document.getElementById("Username").value``` to ```$("#Username").value``` and same like all other ids.

Comment: The jQuery is a JavaScript library, that is, it's an extension written in pure JS. So, you don't hsve to do anything, this will work if you use jQuery as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pure  JS and Jquery can work together, your code always work with or without jquery, but if you want all codes in same format then.

```js
function contantForm()
{
    let Username = $("#Username").val();  
    let Emailinput = $("#Email").val(); 
    alert("Thank you " + Username) 
    $("#Username").val(""); 
    $("#Email").val(""); 
    $("#Phone").val(""); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please remove the code comments, because it denotes wrong what it really does.